# ondataavailable is not called when trying to record webgl2 canvas with MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video, web-mediarecorder

This is the code I use to record canvas from a web browser game to video.

```
let mediaRecorder;
let recordedBlobs;

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const stream = canvas.captureStream(); // frames per second
console.log('Started stream capture from canvas element: ', stream);


function handleDataAvailable(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
  if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
  }
}

function handleStop(event) {
  console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
  const superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
}

function startRecording() {
  let options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
  recordedBlobs = [];
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
  console.log('Created MediaRecorder', mediaRecorder);
  mediaRecorder.onstop = handleStop;
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.start(100);
  console.log('MediaRecorder started', mediaRecorder);
}

function stopRecording() {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
  console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', recordedBlobs);
}

function download() {
  const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'test.webm';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 100);
}
```

For some reason ondataavailable is not called untill recording is stopped, but even then it returns an empty buffer. I've started troubleshooting the issue, so far I figured out the issue is not with the stream, as I've created a video element and injected it into the page, then set its srcObject property to stream and then called video.play() and everything worked correctly, the video was playing exactly what was drawn in the canvas.

However when I call the following:

```
startRecording();

// Wait for some time

stopRecording();

// this downloads an 0 size webm
download();
```

I see that ondataavailable is called only after the recording is stopped and thebuffer is empty. I can't figure out for dear life why it's happening, considering it works for some other canvas games I've tried, but not for this specific one. I've tried looking for an answer, but didn't find anything clear, perhaps it's about codecs, some mention CORS, but I don't see how it's related. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you draw anything on your canvas after you started the recorder? Otherwise, no new frame comes to the MediaStream, and the recorder doesn't see anything and thus doesn't produce anything.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, the canvas has animation loop and it keeps drawing, the outgoing stream sends the data, as tested by linking it directly into video element on the same page. However it seems like MediaRecorder doesn't actually record anything from that stream.

Comment: That's very surprising then, could you try to set up a minimal example where we can see the issue at hand?

Comment: @Kaiido I would even say very mysterious, as I've just tried the same code on my laptop, same version of chrome, Windows 10 on both machines and on laptop it works! To set it up properly I'll somehow have to set up a connection to the game with a dummy account in jsfiddle, not sure if I'll be able through, but I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: What browser? They work differently in this respect.

Comment: @O.Jones I'm giving up on this because I can't figure out for dear life why it doesn't work. It works on Firefox, it works on my CEF C# application, which uses older chrome version, but on latest chrome version it simply doesn't work. In any case I was going to use it to record an offscreen canvas using bot service running in background, so since it works in CEF It's enough for me.